# 'ddply' causes a fatal error in RStudio running correlation on a large data set: ways to optimize?

Tags: r, optimization, rstudio, plyr, correlation

I need to calculate correlations on a large dataset (> 1 million of lines) split by several columns. I try to do it combining `ddply` and `cor()` functions:

```
func <- function(xx) {
 return(data.frame(corB = cor(xx$ysales, xx$bas.sales), 
                   corA = cor(xx$ysales, xx$tysales)))
}

output <- ddply(input, .(IBD,cell,cat), func)
```

This code works pretty well on relatively small data sets (dataframes with 1000 lines or 10000 lines), but causes a 'fatal error' when the input file has 100000 lines or more. So it looks like there is not enough memory on my computer to process such a big file with these functions.

Are there opportunities to optimize such code somehow? Maybe some alternatives to `ddply` work more effectively, or using loops that would split one function into several consecutive?

Comment: This is not reproducible. Please make it.

Comment: Thank you, I've added missed ')' to the post. It was a misprint - in real environment I've been testing the function with the right number of brackets.

I do understand that this exact example is not reproducible :( but maybe there are at least some general recommendations or best practices - what approaches/functions are more effective than ddply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any problems with `ddply` on my machine even with `1e7` rows and data as given below. In total, it uses up approx. 1.7 GB on my machine.
Here is my code:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#this makes your code reproducible
set.seed(1234)
N_rows=1e7
input=data.frame(IBD=sample(letters[1:5],N_rows,TRUE),
                 cell=sample(letters[1:5],N_rows,TRUE),
                 cat=sample(letters[1:5],N_rows,TRUE),
                 ysales=rnorm(N_rows),
                 tysales=rnorm(N_rows),
                 bas.sales=rnorm(N_rows))

#your solution
library(plyr)

func <- function(xx) {
  return(data.frame(corB = cor(xx$ysales, xx$bas.sales), 
                    corA = cor(xx$ysales, xx$tysales)))
}

output <- ddply(input, .(IBD,cell,cat), func)
```

However, in case your problem is more complex than my sample data, you could try the `data.table` package. Here some code (please note that I am not a heavy user of `data.table` and that the code below might be inefficient)

```
library(data.table)

input_dt=data.table(input)

output_dt=unique(input_dt[,`:=`(corB=cor(.SD$ysales,.SD$bas.sales),
                                corA=cor(.SD$ysales,.SD$tysales))
                          ,by=c('IBD','cell','cat')]
                 [,c('IBD','cell','cat','corB','corA'),with=FALSE])

output_dt=output_dt[order(output_dt$IBD,output_dt$cell,output_dt$cat)]
```

It gives the same result

```
all.equal(data.table(output),output_dt)
#[1] TRUE

head(output_dt,3)

#   IBD cell cat          corB          corA
#1:   a    a   a -6.656740e-03 -0.0050483282
#2:   a    a   b  4.758460e-03  0.0051115833
#3:   a    a   c  1.751167e-03  0.0036150088
```

Comment: Thank you so much @cryo111! First, because now I understand how to make the code examples reproducible. Second, because the `data.table` works!
(I've experimented a bit with your input for `data.frame` and found that on my machine it works when I use `1e7` rows and sample data generated by `rnorm`, but continues to cause fatal errors if I use bigger values for the sample data (`rnorm()*100000000`, that is similar to my real dataset values). But with `data.table` it works perfectly!